# Xcode iOS sdk what would be the best server side language?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

What would be the best server side language that the iPhone can easily decode? I'm trying to make a game that stores data on my server then redownloads it, what'd be the best method to do this?

Also can php host a game server?

Comment: The iPhone isn't going to decode anything on the server side.  It will need to be able to "decode" whatever is returned from the server back to the iPhone.  But you can probably generate any kind of output using any kind of server side language.  Because you're possibly sending data over a mobile network (a relatively slow and costly way to send data) you'll probably want to roll your own protocol that a) keeps the size of your packets small and b) ensures that they move as quickly as possible across that slow network. But other standard protocols (XML, JSON) work as well, though "heavier."

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data, you may be able to just stick it out until iCloud launches in iOS 5, if it's user-specific (and unshared/private) data.

Otherwise, just go with what you know. The server-side architecture and transport data structure can be pretty much whatever you want it to be. Whatever language you have some experience in (PHP, servlets, even .NET), go with that to get started.

Comment: In theory, sure.  If all you're doing is periodically saving game data, yep, PHP can definitely do that.  If you're wanting to do more than that, then you'll need to explain your requirements in more detail to get an answer based in reality.  If you're trying to write a server-side engine for a first person shooter, for example, there may be faster solutions.

Comment: I'm wanting to make a server capable of hosting multiple users sorta like an mmog

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Objective-Cloud](http://objective-cloud.com/), it is a so called “I’m an iOS app maker who just needs to do a little server work”, in the same way that Azure is a good platform for Microsoft developers.